# Question about JInternalFrames

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jinternalframe, componentlistener

I have a frame that once it's minimized, I'd like to minimize other frames related to it. If the frame is no longer minimized, I want to restore the other frames too. How should I go about doing this?

EDIT: nvm, it works.

Comment: Exactly how are they related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JInternalFrame.addInternalListener`, and then catch in the `internalFrameDeiconified` method.

Then you can just call `JInternalFrame.setMaximum(true)` on any of the others that are minimized.